# Random effects in gamlss

Tags: mixed-model, prediction, random-effects-model, gamlss

I have a question regarding the gamlss package. I am attempting to fit a mixed effects model using the Befa Inflated distribution as follows

```
gam <- gamlss(y~time+re(random=list(ID=pdDiag(~1+time)),method="REML"),
               sigma.formula=~1,
               nu.formula=~1, 
               tau.formula=~1, 
               family= BEINF,
               data=dat)
```

I wanted to

1) derive estimates for the variance components of the model...i.e. for the random intercept and random coefficient associated with time

2) get predicted values based on new subjects that takes into consideration the random effects so I can do a visual predictive check

What functions calls in gamlss are there to achieve this?

In regard to 1, I am aware of the getSmo function which produces the output below. But from this output it is  not entirely clear what are the variance estimates corresponding to intercept and time.

```
> getSmo(gam2,what="mu")
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: Data 
 Log-likelihood: -19035.68
  Fixed: fix.formula 
(Intercept) 
  0.3913904 

 Random effects:
  Formula: ~1 + time | ID
  Structure: Diagonal
          (Intercept)      time Residual
 StdDev:    1.331172 0.3315697 0.678072

 Variance function:
  Structure: fixed weights
  Formula: ~W.var 
 Number of Observations: 2750
 Number of Groups: 250
```

Comment: This thread on SO may be of some use here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450865/extracting-random-effects-from-a-gamlss-object